# Why is Powershell not recognizing System.Data inside Add_Type block?

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0

I am trying to write a PS script that will open a stored proc, pass parameters and execute that proc, then output the data to a DataSet.  That all seems to work, but whern I try to create a .NET object inside an Add-Type block, I get the error:

> The type or namespace 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System'
>   (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Here's the code:

```
Add-Type @'
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TestObject
{...}
'@
```

The part that's really confusing me is that I create a DataSet in another part of the code, outside of the .NET class, and the reference to System.Data.DataSet works fine.

Any thoughts on this are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add System.Data to the `-ReferencedAssemblies` parameter of `Add-Type`

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the "ReferencedAssemblies" property in this case.  Thanks!